# cannot create absolute file path when deploying in azure

Tags: .net, azure, botframework, filepath

I'm trying to create a chatbot and then deploy it in my azure account the problem is that i need sometimes to post documents in the discussion as a response, and the absolute file path doesn't work when the bot is depolyed in azure but it does work in my localhost.

```
var imagePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Files/mutuelle.pdf");
```

this is the code to generate the file path. When deploying is in azure the link to file is :

> https://*******.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/Files/mutuelle.pdf

and i guess the problem is that the imagePath variable is only

> https://*******.azurewebsites.net/Files/mutuelle.pdf.

So i have a problem generating the absolute file path in azure (dev/wwwroot/).
Can someone show me the solution please ?

Comment: I do not understand the relation between Server.MapPath and the URL you posted ("https://....)   Server.MapPath returns a physical path on server harddisk, like  c:\inetpub\.....

Comment: Also, don't do that, don't write to your app's storage, use `%TEMP%` which maps to `d:\local` on App Service as temporary storage, or better yet, upload to blob storage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a folder in your project say /Contents and keep all the files you need to sent in that folder.

When deployed to Azure you can add your hosted url to the web.config file as

```
<appSettings>      
<add key="HostedUrl" value="https://**.azurewebsites.net/Content/" />
<appSettings>
```

Then in your dialog you can set the image path as:

```
private static string contentUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["HostedUrl"];    
var imageUrl = contentUrl + "imageName.png";
```

Comment: i think this will only work when deployed to  azure but not on localhost. Is there something that'll work on both ?

Comment: It will work on your localhost too. You just need to change the hosted url to your localhost address.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I access my file on Azure with a relative path with the following command, my file is in a Credential folder on my VS project and everything is working fine.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("..\\Credential\\XXX.json");
```

Comment: when i do this i can see that the path given to me is D:\home\site\wwwroot\Files\mutuelle.pdf
but the path should be like this :
https://*******.azurewebsites.net/dev/wwwroot/Files/mutuelle.pdf

Comment: I do not unserstand why you absolutely want to have an URL and not a physical path.

Comment: because when i test my bot in azure the file is no longer recognized as if there's no file there. What i want is a path that works on both localhost and azure.